# Log settings location of Magento 2

Tags: magento2, admin-panel, log

I would like to know the below **2 locations of Magento 1 in Magento 2**.  Where can I find these 2 locations in Magento 2 Admin Panel ?

First location

[image]

Second location

[image]

Answer (score 16):

Unfortunately, those options are gone now in Magento.

Regarding the visitor log, everything is logged via the `\Magento\Customer\Model\Logger` model and via events observers declared under `\Magento\Customer\etc\frontend\events.xml`.

However, the automatic cleaning seems to be totally gone.

Regarding the system and exceptions logs, same issue, it's not configurable via the backend anymore and it's hardcoded directly in the following classes:

- `\Magento\Framework\Logger\Handler\Debug.php` when you use the debug level, logs will go to `/var/log/debug.log`
- `\Magento\Framework\Logger\Handler\Exception.php` when you use the exception level, logs will go to `/var/log/exception.log`
- `\Magento\Framework\Logger\Handler\System.php` when you use the system level, 
  logs will got to `/var/log/system.log`

Comment: Then, how can we use custom logging?
Lets say if I want to do something like this:
Mage::log($collectionData, null, 'collectionData.log');
How can I check my logs?

Comment: @AbhishekDhanrajShahdeo I suggest you check this question: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92434/magento-2-replacement-for-magelog-method

Comment: is there any way to disable it ? i want to disable system log permanently

Comment: So, the definitive answer is no? Is no way to disable or clean the logs? That sounds pretty impractical. Why the change?

Answer (score -2):

If you want to log your variables you can do this way.

```
<?php
namespace Test\Testpayment\Observer;

class Sendtogateway implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
  protected $_responseFactory;
  protected $_url;
  protected $order;
  protected $logger;
  protected $_checkoutSession;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory $responseFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url,
    \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface $order,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $loggerInterface,
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
    ){
        $this->_responseFactory = $responseFactory;
    $this->_url = $url;
    $this->order = $order;
        $this->logger = $loggerInterface;
    $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
    }

  public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
  {

     $id = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getIncrementId();
     $this->_checkoutSession->setOrderNo($id);
     $orderdetail = $this->order->loadByIncrementId($id);
     $customerBeforeAuthUrl = $this->_url->getUrl('testpay/index/index/');
     $this->_responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($customerBeforeAuthUrl)->sendResponse();
     $this->logger->debug('$id');
  }
}
```

Comment: This answer not belong to the question

Comment: It is not the correct way.