# Magento 2: How to Disable System/Exception Log

Tags: magento2, log

In Magento 2 not getting Log Setting option in admin under developer,

How can Disable System log and Exception Log.

Answer (score 0):

In magento2 this option is not exist,the setting has been removed from admin area.while you can set by using some function.

For more info check link:

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/110369