# Unable to locate error log

Tags: error, magento-2.1, log

I have a fresh installation on a hosted environment and setting up my store. In an attempt to see if email is working i tried using the contact us page (default). However i get an error "We can't process your request right now. Sorry, that's all we know.". I am trying to locate the error log in directory var/log, but unable to find in any of the files there. Is there anything i am doing wrong.

I am using community edition version 2.1.

Thanks

Comment: check var/log permission try 777 and also set to developer mode

Comment: var/log has 666 permission

Answer (score 0):

Your log files should be located under root magento folder in var/log. Please check the answer here, maybe they can answer you how to log in Magento 2. [Magento 2 logs file and methods](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92434/magento-2-replacement-for-magelog-method)

Comment: Hi - None of the log files in the location var/log contain the exception trace from where i could derive information. Should i do any setting for execptions to log.