# Technical Review Failed on: deploy:mode:set production

Tags: memory, setup-di-compile, product-review

I recently **submitted a module to the Magento Marketplace** for Technical review; it got rejected with the following error:

> Command returned non-zero exit code: php -f /var/www/html/bin/magento
>   setup:di:compile-multi-tenant 2>&1

When I run the above command on my test store, I get the following error:

> PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 52428800 bytes exhausted
>   (tried to allocate 73728 bytes) in
>   /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on
>   line 94

Obviously as this is being done by the Technical Review I can't use the `-dmemory_limit=6G` parameter that has been suggested on a few Magento Stack answers.

I've tried adding `ini_set('memory_limit' ,'50M')` to the php files but it still seems to be getting the same error.

What are generally the causes for this in a module? And any potential solutions for the module that could prevent this from happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to the 
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/trouble/php/tshoot_php-set.html#trouble-php-memory - memory limit should be 2G.
On our docker images we have memory_limit = 2048М. [Errors during installation- Submitting Package to Magento Marketplace](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/158910/errors-during-installation-submitting-package-to-magento-marketplace/159675#159675) - here we already done this.

Try to increase your memory_limit settings and rerun command

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile-multi-tenant
```

in your project root directory.

Comment: Hi Eduard. Unfortunately this doesn't solve the problem of it erroring whilst running through the Technical Review. As this is run by Magento, so the limit can't be changed.