# How to run cron file via browser in magento2

Tags: magento2, cron

I have created a logic that look seems fine if I run that via controller file. But I am getting an error while running via cron (checked via log file), using magento2 cron process.

ModuleName/Cron/Myfile.php

Is there any way that I can run this file directly via browser to debug the things?

Please reply ASAP!

Comment: Might be a permission issue. Are you running cron with server owner permissions?

Comment: Brother, Okay, but "Is there any way that I can run cron file via browser ?"

Answer (score 0):

To run a php file in a browser from your module, you need to temporarily disable the .htaccess file in your **app** folder.

For example, rename it to .htaccess2.

Then you can browse the file in your browser like this:

`http://domain.com/app/code/{vendor}/{module}/Cron/Yourfile.php`

Just don't forget to return the .htaccess file back to normal after debugging.

**EDIT**

You can test functions by calling your file through browser like this:
http://domain.com/path/to/cron/file/?function=testFunction

And in your cron php file, you can make a switch statement to call your functions like this:

```
switch($_GET['function']) {
    case 'testFunction':
        testFunction();
}

function testFunction() {
    echo 'test';
    // your cron logic
}

... //other functions
```

Although for debugging purposes, maybe you could use Magento's log functions to debug your problem.

See this question for more info: [Magento 2: Replacement for Mage::log method?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92434/magento-2-replacement-for-magelog-method).

Comment: its showing blank page .....

Comment: @Atul that means you execute the php file, but don't print/echo anything. Try echoing something in your file.

Comment: in execute function i applied "echo 'helloooo'; "...Is it ryt ?

Comment: Check my edit for more info.