# magento 2 how to print log

Tags: admin-panel, log, magento2.3

After installing Magento 2.3, When I am trying to open the admin panel login screen is blank and my console contains an error as shown in the image. if anyone has a solution then please let me know.

magento 2 how to print log???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento 2: Replacement for Mage::log method?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92434/magento-2-replacement-for-magelog-method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/test.log');
$logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$logger->info('Your text message');

You can also print PHP objects and arrays like below :

$logger->info(print_r($yourArray, true));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use this plugin for download logs from admin panel - https://github.com/metasyncSite/Magento-2-log-viewer