# Magento2: how to debug in sales_order_place_after event

Tags: orders, event-observer, magento2.3, log, debugging

**registration.php**

```
 <?php
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Hafiz_Sms',
    __DIR__
    );
```

**etc/events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configxmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
<eventname="sales_order_place_after">
<observername="place_order_after" instance="Hafiz\Sms\Observer\Orderplaceafter" />
</event>
</config>
```

**etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
<module name="Hafiz_Sms" setup_version="2.1.1"></module>
</config>
```

**Observer/Orderplaceafter.php**

```
<?php
namespace Hafiz\Sms\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
class Orderplaceafter implements ObserverInterface
{
protected $logger;
public function __construct(LoggerInterface$logger) {
$this->logger = $logger;
}
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer){
  $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
  echo $orderId = $order->getId();
//  $comment = $this->getRequest()->getParam('comment');
  print_r("Catched event succssfully !"); exit;
}
}
```

But it's not working. How to debug in this event?. Kindly suggest me where i am wrong?

Comment: Not sure if it's just a typo in the question but `<eventname` should be `<event name` and `<observername` should be `<observer name`. That could be your problem if that's how it is in the module.

Comment: Hi Hafiz Arslan.are you completed debugging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event will be defined at `etc/events.xml` Nor `etc/event.xml`.Seems file name is wrong.

`events.xml`code will be like.Also, the Syntax of declare event is wrong. Please used below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_order_place_after">
        <observer name="place_order_after" instance="Hafiz\Sms\Observer\Orderplaceafter" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Follow this article for how to implement event at module https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/events-and-observers.html.

Forgetting purpose, don't use **print_r, die and exit**. Use Magento loggger for print for  debugging [Magento 2: Replacement for Mage::log method?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92434/magento-2-replacement-for-magelog-method)

Comment: it redirect  checkout/cart page .
not show print_r("Catched event succssfully !"); exit; this one?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is an interesting question. Many people may know about **`sales_order_place_after`** event.

If you use this event, you can't use print_r() and exit() function.

Otherwise, kindly use **`checkout_onepage_controller_success_action`** event. It will a helpful lot

Comment: checkout_onepage_controller_success_action is this event order place  event?

Comment: This event  use for after order placed

Answer (score 0):

You declared `event name` and `observer name` as `observername` and `eventname`.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configxmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
<event name="sales_order_place_after">
<observer name="place_order_after" instance="Hafiz\Sms\Observer\Orderplaceafter" />
</event>
</config>
```