# Magento 2 - How to add logs inside module

Tags: magento2, third-party-module, psr-logger

I have added like below way. But it doesn't work for that module

```
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

/**
 * @var LoggerInterface
 */
protected $logger;

protected $resultForwardFactory;

public function __construct(
    Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory $fileFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Translate\InlineInterface $translateInline,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\LayoutFactory $resultLayoutFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RawFactory $resultRawFactory,
    \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\ForwardFactory $resultForwardFactory,
    LoggerInterface $logger
) {
    $this->_coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
    $this->_fileFactory = $fileFactory;
    $this->_translateInline = $translateInline;
    $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
    $this->resultLayoutFactory = $resultLayoutFactory;
    $this->resultRawFactory = $resultRawFactory;
    $this->resultForwardFactory = $resultForwardFactory;

    $this->logger = $logger;
    parent::__construct($context);
}




 /**
     * @return void
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $this->resource->getConnection()->beginTransaction();
        try {
            $this->_prepare();
            $this->_execute();
            $this->resource->getConnection()->commit();
            $this->logger->info('Test');

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->resource->getConnection()->rollBack();
            $this->logger->info($e);
            throw $e;
        }
        $this->getFlag()->save();
    }
```

Comment: where you are checking your log i.e in which file ?

Comment: Please also confirm your run function is executing.

Comment: Im checking debug log inside magento var/log folder

Comment: in var/log which specific file ?

Comment: Im checking debug.log file

Comment: you used `info` in logger so please check in `system.log`

Comment: people like easy code instead of standard code :)

Comment: https://techurbane.com/how-to-add-custom-logs-in-magento-2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code for Magento versions prior to 2.4.2.

```
$writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/custom.log');
$logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$logger->info('Custom message') 
$logger->info(print_r($object->getData(), true));
```

Use the following code for Magento 2.4.2

```
$writer = new \Laminas\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/custom.log');
$logger = new  \Laminas\Log\Logger();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$logger->info('text message');
```

Use the following code for Magento 2.4.3

```
$writer = new \Zend_Log_Writer_Stream(BP . '/var/log/custom.log');
$logger = new \Zend_Log();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$logger->info('text message');
```

Answer (score 3):

you can do this simple way ..

```
$writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/test.log');
$logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$logger->info('Your text message');
```

Comment: This worked for me simply. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your code seems correct to me.

if your `run` function is executing, there should be log present in log file.

As per my observation you are looking in wrong log file.

if you added `$this->logger->info('Test');`, Your log should be present in `system.log`.

for more info please look at [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92434/magento-2-replacement-for-magelog-method)

Answer (score 1):

You can use any of the following methods. sure one of them will work.

```
**Method 1:**  

    $writer = new \Zend_Log_Writer_Stream(BP . '/var/log/customfile.log');
    $logger = new \Zend_Log();
    $logger->addWriter($writer);
    $logger->info('I am logged from Zend_log_writer');
   
**Method 2:**

    $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/logfileZend.log');
    $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
    $logger->addWriter($writer);
    $logger->info('Simple Text Log from Zend logger 2'); // Simple Text Log

**Method 3:**

    $writer = new \Laminas\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/customlaminas.log');
    $logger = new \Laminas\Log\Logger();
    $logger->addWriter($writer);
    $logger->info("log from laminas log");
```