# What is the query readers here i can't understand magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, query, eav-attributes, database-connection

I can't find the what query rendes here and i can't it is not readable so any can to find what query renders hear please tell what are the table involved here

```
 public function getCount(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\FilterInterface $filter)
    {
        // clone select from collection with filters
        $select = clone $filter->getLayer()->getProductCollection()->getSelect();
        // reset columns, order and limitation conditions
        $select->reset(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::COLUMNS);
        $select->reset(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::ORDER);
        $select->reset(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::LIMIT_COUNT);
        $select->reset(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::LIMIT_OFFSET);

        $connection = $this->getConnection();
        $attribute = $filter->getAttributeModel();
        $tableAlias = sprintf('%s_idx', $attribute->getAttributeCode());
        $conditions = [
            "{$tableAlias}.entity_id = e.entity_id",
            $connection->quoteInto("{$tableAlias}.attribute_id = ?", $attribute->getAttributeId()),
            $connection->quoteInto("{$tableAlias}.store_id = ?", $filter->getStoreId()),
        ];

        $select->join(
            [$tableAlias => $this->getMainTable()],
            join(' AND ', $conditions),
            ['value', 'count' => new \Zend_Db_Expr("COUNT({$tableAlias}.entity_id)")]
        )->group(
            "{$tableAlias}.value"
        );

        return $connection->fetchPairs($select);
    }
```

Comment: Dont worry this is not array when echo this before return.

Answer (score 0):

Before return you can print this and check which table you want.

```
  echo $select->__toString();
```

Comment: How can print if it is array?

Comment: echo used and die;

Comment: It is not working bro if i put die also it is coming

Comment: If die is not working here so please check its overide.

Comment: No it is not overrided it is a model file it is only in vendor/*

Comment: you can check in inspect element as well

Comment: Do you know from were the product count is renders for the layered navigation in filter side bar

Answer (score 0):

instead of dying, you can log the query:

you may use these 3 lines:

```
$writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/querytounderstand.log');
$logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$logger->info($select->__toString()); // as per Jijay suggestion
```

Add a log in Magento is talke about here:
[Magento 2: Replacement for Mage::log method?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92434/magento-2-replacement-for-magelog-method)