# Magento2: What is the process to create custom logger

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0, logging

**How I can create my own custom logger in magento2 ?**

In Magento 1, We simply write own custom log with the following code:

```
Mage::log("Log Message", null, "log_file.log");
```

Comment: $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/mylog.log');
              $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
              $logger->addWriter($writer);
              $logger->info("Your comment ".$variables);

Comment: I think the right duplicate question/answer is here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/75935/how-to-create-custom-log-file-in-magento-2/75954#75954

Answer (score 0):

For logging OR creating log file, you should use class `"Magento\Framework\Logger\Monolog"`.

For more see here : http://inchoo.net/magento-2/magento-2-logging/