# Zend Logger - Dependency injection with required parameters

Tags: magento2, log, dependency-injection

I want to **log info to a specific file in magento2.**

This does the job:

```
$writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/test.log');
$logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$logger->info('Your text message');
```

but I want to use it with DI.

I am getting this error:

```
Missing required argument $streamOrUrl of Zend\Log\Writer\Stream.
```

I am not sure about the syntax of DI when there are required parameters. Tried a few ways but it doesn't work:

```
use Zend\Log\Writer\Stream;
use Zend\Log\Logger;

    public $logger;

    public $writer;

    public function __construct(
        Logger $logger,
        Stream $writer
    ) {
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->writer = $writer;
        $this->logger->addWriter($this->writer(BP . '/var/log/test.log'));
        $this->logger->info('Start');
    }
```

If someone can show me how to use `\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface` to write to a custom log file it will be even better.

Thanks!

Comment: follow this link http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/75935/logging-to-a-custom-file-in-magento-2  I hope this is usefull for you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't think you can do that via DI.

The problem, as the error mentions, is that **the first argument of `Zend\Log\Writer\Stream` is required and AFAIK, DI does not let you specify an argument when injecting classes.**

Two possible solutions here:

- use `\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface` but you won't be able to write to a custom class
- create your own log class based on `Monolog\Logger` : [Logging to a custom file in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/75935/logging-to-a-custom-file-in-magento-2)

### Possible alternative

This needs to be tested but I think you can create your own class extending `Zend\Log\Writer\Stream`

Then in your `di.xml` you can specify the argument:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Vendor\Module\Model\My\Log\Class">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="streamOrUrl" xsi:type="string">/var/log/test.log</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

Then you can inject that class in your constructor.

Theorically I think that could work.