# How to change default file log name in Magento 2 in Psr Logger?

Tags: magento2, log, logging, psr-logger

I have an instance of a logger in my PHP script that I use. I instantiate it like this:

```
$logger = $om->get("Psr\Log\LoggerInterface");
```

I can log text like this:

```
$logger->debug("caruk");
```

but it is always logged in the file `var/log/debug.log` . I want to log error messages in my own custom file `customfile.log` . How can I do this?

Comment: This looks like a duplicate question, see this answer for how to create a custom log file: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/75935/logging-to-a-custom-file-in-magento-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want to define your own logger using monolog you can follow https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/75954/9169.

If you want to change default debug log file you can rewrite `Magento\Framework\Logger\Handler\Debug` in your custom module and change filename there.

Module's `di.xml` code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Framework\Logger\Handler\Debug" type="Amit\Helloworld\Model\CustomLogger" />
</config>
```

`CustomLogger.php` code

```
<?php

namespace Amit\Helloworld\Model;
use Monolog\Logger;

class CustomLogger extends \Magento\Framework\Logger\Handler\Debug
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $fileName = '/var/log/customfile.log';

    /**
     * @var int
     */
    protected $loggerType = Logger::DEBUG;
}
```

Now your debug logs will be logged in `customfile.log` .

Example:

```
<?php

namespace Amit\Helloworld\Controller\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    // other code
    protected $logger;

    public function __construct(
        // other code
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {
        // other code
        $this->logger = $logger;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $this->logger->debug('test');
        // other code
    }

}
```

Similarly you can overwrite other default log files `exception.log` and `system.log` using preference. Other log files are defined in `\Magento\Framework\Logger\Handler\Exception`, `\Magento\Framework\Logger\Handler\System`

Answer (score 0):

Please try below if you do not want to create a module:

```
$writer = new \Zend_Log_Writer_Stream(BP .'/var/log/customfile.log');
$logger = new \Zend_Log();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$logger->info('hello log');
```