# Magento 2 custom logger 'Missing required argument $name'

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, log, di

I'm trying to create a custom logger, so I can log to a custom log file.

I've looked at and followed multiple tutorials that all say the same, however I keep getting the same error.

Tutorials that I followed:

- http://www.thienphucvx.com/magento-2-logging-to-a-custom-file/
- https://www.maximehuran.fr/en/logs-and-magento-2/
- https://ranasohel.me/2016/06/26/how-to-create-a-custom-logger-in-magento-2/
- [How to create custom Log file in Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/75935/how-to-create-custom-log-file-in-magento-2)

This is not a duplicate of [How to create custom Log file in Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/75935/how-to-create-custom-log-file-in-magento-2) as I followed everything that was explained there but got this error regardless.

I keep receiving the error: `Missing required argument $name of Burst\MageNinjaApi\Logger\Logger.`, but far as I am aware, I am supplying the argument `$name` with `<argument name="name" xsi:type="string">MageNinjaApiLogger</argument>` in `etc/di.xml`.

Magento version: 2.1.10

---

**app/code/Burst/MageNinjaApi/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Burst\MageNinjaApi\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface" type="Burst\MageNinjaApi\Catalog\ProductRepository" />
    <preference for="Burst\MageNinjaApi\Quote\Api\GuestCartItemRepositoryInterface" type="Burst\MageNinjaApi\Quote\GuestCartItemRepository" />
    <preference for="Burst\MageNinjaApi\Quote\Api\Data\CartItemInterface" type="Burst\MageNinjaApi\Quote\Item" />

    <!-- Custom Logger -->
    <type name="Burst\MageNinjaApi\Logger\Handler\Debug">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="filesystem" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <type name="Burst\MageNinjaApi\Logger\Logger">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">MageNinjaApiLogger</argument>
            <argument name="handlers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="debug" xsi:type="object">Burst\MageNinjaApi\Logger\Handler\Debug</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

**app/code/Burst/MageNinjaApi/Logger/Logger.php**

```
<?php

namespace Burst\MageNinjaApi\Logger;

class Logger extends \Monolog\Logger {

}
```

**app/code/Burst/MageNinjaApi/Logger/Handler/Debug.php**

```
<?php

namespace Burst\MageNinjaApi\Logger\Handler;

use Magento\Framework\Logger\Handler\Base;
use Monolog\Logger;

class Debug extends Base {
  protected $fileName = '/var/log/MageNinjaApi/debug.log';
  protected $loggerType = Logger::DEBUG;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create custom Log file in Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/75935/how-to-create-custom-log-file-in-magento-2)

Comment: It's not a duplicate. I followed the instructions on that page as I explained in my post (see under "Tutorials that I followed".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have encountered this problem as you had. The problem is the new configuration:
`<argument name="name" xsi:type="string">MageNinjaApiLogger</argument>` in `etc/di.xml` is not updated.

Run `php bin/magento cache:flush` to update `di.xml` => It will solve this problem.

Comment: I did not test this but it sounds very plausible. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Yes. I have tested it.

Comment: I tested it and it worked (Magento 2.4.4-p3)

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, I ran into this error when I forgot to enable my logger module, but I enabled a different module that depended on it. Could be a missing dependency.

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved by updating Magento to version 2.2.1.
I did not find out what caused the problem.

Comment: This doesn't really add anything to the issue, seems likely the upgrade to a higher version meant you'd cleared the cache which is the accepted answer.