# Where to find Payment Log file in Magento 2?

Tags: payment-methods, magento2.2.3, log

I want to check if there is any failed transactions occurred on our site. I'm aware that this detail can get from Payment Log file but for my case, there is no Payment Log file is available under var/log folder.

We are using DIBS payment method. Please let me know where to find the Payment Log file in Magento 2.

Comment: Are you using any extension for this payment method?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your `payment module` if the developer has added the **exceptions** and **php warning** in a specific log file, it can quite inject them into the native Magento logs `exception`, `system`.

You have to check in the module (code and configuration), otherwise you can add them yourself by following this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/75935/how-to-create-custom-log-file-in-magento-2) and so you you will update the module.