# Creating event and observer for an action at backend of Magento 2

Tags: event-observer, magento2.3

How to create an custom event and observer for that event at backend in Magento2. For example I want to create an event that whenever an admin deletes a customer profile a separate log file is generated. Please help me with the detailed solution and the directory structure.

Comment: There is no option to delete the order in magento 2.....You can create event as `order_cancel_after` for cancel the order.

Comment: Ok thank  you I have updated my question

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using plugin instead of events

Create di.xml in `app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepository">
        <plugin name="customer_delete_around" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\aroundCustomerDelete" />
    </type>
</config>
```

And create a plugin with below code in `Vendor\Module\Plugin\aroundCustomerDelete.php`

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

class aroundCustomerDelete
{
    public function aroundDeleteById(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepository $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        $customerId
    ) {
        // This will proceed delete action
        $result = $proceed($customerId);

        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/test.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        $logger->info('Your text message');

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Or you can create a custom log file using [This link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/75935/how-to-create-custom-log-file-in-magento-2#75954)

Or use `customer_delete_before` this event to run your script in observer

Comment: I have already executed it using plugin I want to know if its possible using event and observer

Comment: I have updated my answer....if you need demo let me know