# Magento 2 - Create a log file in plugin that will print log when data is inserted in database

Tags: database, magento2.3, log, after-plugin

I have entered data in the database using object Manager in Model file itself. I want to print a log file from the plugin that will print the log of the last data that is inserted in the database.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/75935/how-to-create-custom-log-file-in-magento-2

Comment: Yes I checked that post. but could not solve my problem

Comment: you need to print last inserted data in your custom named log file right ?

Comment: yes. fetch the data from the database using id and print the log and this has to be done in Plugin file

Comment: please provide the data fetching code ?

Comment: how to fetch that data i require that too

Comment: fetch Id if Id is present then print the log that will contain details of all the columns

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97708/discussion-between-shafeel-sha-and-naiwrita09).

Comment: You can use \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Psr\Log\LoggerInterface')->debug('your data');

Answer (score 1):

To generate log file you can use below code. add pass data as per your need.

```
$writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/logfile.log');
$logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$logger->info('Simple Text Log'); // Simple Text Log
$logger->info('Array Log'.print_r($myArrayVar, true)); // Array Log
```

For more information read this. [Magento 2: Replacement for Mage::log method?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92434/magento-2-replacement-for-magelog-method)

Comment: Actually I want to know the fetching of data. how to get the id and print the data accordingly.

Comment: Hi @Naiwrita09, Please check my comment and see if that can help

Comment: ok I will check and let you know @RahulAnand

Answer (score 0):

Your need to create a plugin for "Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel" for "afterSave" method and log all the logs in that. AbstractModel executes all the time for all the model save.

In your di.xml file declare the plugin:

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel">
<plugin name="log_query" type="Magento\ExternalLinks\Plugin\logQuery" sortOrder="1" />
```

in your plugin file log the data.

```
namespace Magento\ExternalLinks\Plugin;

class LogQuery
{
    public function afterSave(\Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel $subject, $result)
    {
        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/logfile.log');
         $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
         $logger->addWriter($writer);
         $logger->info(var_dump($result));
        return $result;
    }
}
```