# How to create custom log file in magento 2

Tags: magento2, custom, log

Can anyone help me in creating custom logger file in mmagento 2.
I want to display collection object in log file.
So far, i have tried this code but did not work.
getting $collection object from public function massAction(AbstractCollection $collection)

```
$writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/pdf.log');
    $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
    $logger->addWriter($writer);
    $logger->info("Hello");
    $logger->info(print_r($collection->debug()));
```

This is what i have tried yet.

Comment: Please refer to https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/75935/how-to-create-custom-log-file-in-magento-2

Comment: @SanjibChowdhury i am getting this error in exception.log file SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory {"exception":"[object] (Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception(code: 2002): SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory at /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php:144, PDOException(code: 2002): SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory at /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php:128)"} []

Comment: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]  comes due to DB connection failed. please check if your database engine is working fine or not.

Comment: https://techurbane.com/how-to-add-custom-logs-in-magento-2/

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code for Magento versions prior to 2.4.2.

```
$writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/custom.log');
$logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$logger->info('Custom message') 
$logger->info(print_r($object->getData(), true));
```

Use the following code for Magento 2.4.2

```
$writer = new \Laminas\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/custom.log');
$logger = new  \Laminas\Log\Logger();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$logger->info('text message');
```

Use the following code for Magento 2.4.3

```
$writer = new \Zend_Log_Writer_Stream(BP . '/var/log/custom.log');
$logger = new \Zend_Log();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$logger->info('text message');
```

Answer (score 0):

Create  Module/Namespace/etc/di.xml and add below config in the file.

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">


  <!-- Log generation process -->
<type name="Module\Namespace\Logger\Handler">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="filesystem" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
<type name="Module\Namespace\Logger\Logger">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="name"      xsi:type="string">Module/Namespace</argument>
        <argument name="handlers"  xsi:type="array">
            <item name="debug"     xsi:type="object">Module\Namespace\Logger\Handler</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>   
</type>
```

Create Module/Namespace/Logger/Handler.php

```
    namespace Module\Namespace\Logger;

    use Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DriverInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Logger\Handler\Base;
    use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface;  
    class Handler extends Base {

        public function __construct(
            DriverInterface $filesystem
        ) {

            $this->fileName = "/var/log/pdf.log";
            parent::__construct($filesystem);
        }

    }
```

Create Module/Namespace/Logger/Logger.php

```
class Logger extends \Monolog\Logger
{

}
```

Now use Module\Namespace\Logger\Logger instead of Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

```
namespace Module\Namespace\Model;

use Module\Namespace\Logger\Logger;


class Association
{


     /**
     * @var Logger
     */
    protected $logger;

    /**
     * __construct
     * 
     * @param Logger $logger
     */
    public function __construct(

        Logger $logger
    )
    {


        $this->logger = $logger;
    }


    /**
     * Generating log
     * 
     * @param string $email
     * @param string $name
     */
    public function generateLog($email, $name)
    {
        $logMessage = array(
            'Email' => $email,
            'Name' => $name
        );

        $this->logger->log(100, json_encode($logMessage));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the following methods. sure one of them will work.

```
**Method 1:**  

    $writer = new \Zend_Log_Writer_Stream(BP . '/var/log/customfile.log');
    $logger = new \Zend_Log();
    $logger->addWriter($writer);
    $logger->info('I am logged from Zend_log_writer');
   
**Method 2:**

    $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/logfileZend.log');
    $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
    $logger->addWriter($writer);
    $logger->info('Simple Text Log from Zend logger 2'); // Simple Text Log

**Method 3:**

    $writer = new \Laminas\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/customlaminas.log');
    $logger = new \Laminas\Log\Logger();
    $logger->addWriter($writer);
    $logger->info("log from laminas log");
```