# PHP 7: How to create a separate log file in PHP to log only the order data(Order info retrieved from an Magento Order object)?

Tags: php, error, log, error-log, webserver

I have an application developed to manage the orders, vendors and many more things.  The default error_log() functionality has already been in use across the application coded in PHP to log not only the errors but order object data to a file called error_log.txt.

I'm looking for a way to log order-specific data to a separate log file so that this data resides in this file as long as I want it to. Could you please guide me in the right direction to achieve this?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/75954/70343

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create the log file in PHP please try the below code:

```
//Write data to log file
$log  = "Order: ".$orderdata.PHP_EOL."-------------------------".PHP_EOL;

//generate the file 
file_put_contents('./order_data_'.date('d-M-Y').'.log', $log, FILE_APPEND);
```

In Magento2, you can create the custom log file using `Zend library`

```
$writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/order_data.log');
$logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$logger->info(print_r($order->getData(), true));
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, it does help accomplish what I was trying to do. Thank you also for the instructions on doing it in Magento 2.

Comment: Bhaumik, could you please tell me if the order_data.log doesn't exist in the folder, will it be created by the error_log() in my code snippet. `{ $log_file = POMS_LOG_FOLDER . "/order_data.log"; 
    $log  = $order_message . PHP_EOL . "-------------------------" . PHP_EOL;
 // logging order info to custom log file 
 error_log($log, 3, $log_file); 
}`

Comment: @CodeForGood Not sure about error_log but with file_put_contents it will be generated if not exist!

Comment: Thanks, I found out the answer. It will be generated as is the case with file_put_contents.