# How to generate custom log file in magento 2?

Tags: log, code

I have tried generating custom log file using helper and logger but the file did not generate.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/75935/how-to-create-custom-log-file-in-magento-2

Comment: https://techurbane.com/how-to-add-custom-logs-in-magento-2/

Answer (score 1):

Put below code in anywhere in magento2 :-

```
$writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/custom.log');
$logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$logger->info($yourData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Logger format depends on the magento version. so i have given different formats as per magento version support. please check and try on it.

**Magento use below code for 2.4.3 and above versions.**

```
$writer = new \Zend_Log_Writer_Stream(BP . '/var/log/custom.log');
$logger = new \Zend_Log();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$logger->info('Test the log');
$logger->info(print_r($object->getData(), true));
```

**Magento use below code for Magento 2.4.2 and below versions.**

```
$writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/custom.log');
$logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$logger->info('Custom message'); 
$logger->info(print_r($object->getData(), true));
```